# WordPress nonce

Tags: wordpress, security, nonce

Hi I'm trying to get into Wordpress Ajax Requests right now. Now I have finished a script that works perfectly. But since I'm not a security professional, I'd like to ask you if you can help me.

I would also like to know if I have to use a form every time or if I can start a request directly via jQuery Ajax. If so, how do I do that with dynamic requests where I can not set the nonce before? e.g. in a list where each entry has multiple buttons?

Many Thanks!

template-form.php

```
<form method="post" id="form">
 <input type="text" name="form_name" />
 <?php wp_nonce_field( 'form_action', 'form_nonce' ); ?>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

script.js

```
jQuery("#submit").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
jQuery.post(ajaxurl + "/ajax.php", jQuery("#form").serialize()).done(function (data) {
  alert(data);
});
return false;
});
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

if( isset( $_POST['form_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['form_nonce'], 'form_action') ) {
     $form_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['form_name']);
     echo "is working";
    }else{
     echo "not working";
     wp_die();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

> I would also like to know if I have to use a form every time or if I
>   can start a request directly via jQuery Ajax. If so, how do I do that
>   with dynamic requests where I can not set the nonce before? e.g. in a
>   list where each entry has multiple buttons?

No you could also use wp_nonce_url to make ajax calls.
But as far as I know, I will not work if you have a multisite installation and send an ajax call from one blog of the network to another blog.

Apart from that, you code looks ok to me and you are also saying that it is working.
Therefore I am confused where exactly you need help.
Could you clarify your question, please?